# (Swift) moving objects while iterating over array

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am trying to remove some objects from 1 array, and move them to another.
I am doing this by removing them from a reversed array, and adding them to another array, like so:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
var array2 = [1,2]
for (index, number) in array1.enumerated().reversed() {
    if(number>2) {
        array1.remove(at: index)
        array2.append(number)
    }
}
```

The problem is, the objects in array 2 are obviously reversed (1,2,6,5,4,3)
I can easily come up with complicated workarounds, but I was wondering if there are any straightforward ways of doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so what is a problem? what do you want to do?

Comment: use filter for array

Comment: If your problem is reversed array2, you can always insert in front of array2 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `append`ing the numbers `insert` them

```
array2.insert(number, at: 2)
```

You can do the same thing without a loop

```
let droppedItems = array1.dropFirst(2)
array1.removeLast(array1.count - 2)
array2.append(contentsOf: droppedItems)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to move numbers from `array1` to `array2` if they are higher than 2:

```
// get only numbers higher than 2 and append them to the second array
array2.append(contentsOf: array1.filter { $0 > 2 })
// filter the moved items from the first array
array1 = array1.filter { $0 <= 2 }
```

or

```
// split the array into two parts in place
let index = array1.partition { $0 > 2 }
// move the second part
array2 += array1[index...]
// remove the second part
array1.removeSubrange(index...)
```

Comment: Not entirely, it is just a simplified version of my code. But still thanks, I have never used filters before so I'm learning from this.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse it, grab subarray then append to array2. You don't need to mutate array1. Something like:

```
array2.append(contentsOf: array1.reversed()[0..<array1.count-1])
```